How do i change the size of my Text widget?
I really need to change the size of textbox but I keep on getting nothing. Here is code:
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwarg):
        self.master = master #self.master is calling 1 argument from function. = master is giving some sort of name u can call later from this function and class
        self.open_chat()
    def open_chat(self):    
        self.textbox = tk.Text(self.master, wrap = WORD) #wrap = WPRD moves the text to a new line as soon as it is reaching the end of pannel
        #pannel for entering the text   adding self to make it global for all the functions in the class
        self.chatbox = tk.Text(self.master, wrap = "word")#showing the text
        scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master)
        send = ttk.Button(self.master, text = "Send", command = self.send_a_message)
        scroll.config(command=self.chatbox.yview)
        self.chatbox.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, state = "disabled")
        self.chatbox.grid(column=0, row=0,sticky='NSWE')
        self.textbox.grid(column=0, row=1,sticky='NSWE')
        send.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='NSW')
        scroll.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='NSW')

    def send_a_message(self):
        self.chatbox.config(state="normal")
        content = self.textbox.get('1.0','end') #from 0 first char to the end
        self.chatbox.insert(END, content) #insert(END, text) to append text to the widget.
        self.chatbox.config(state="disabled")
        self.textbox.delete('1.0',END)

win = tk.Tk()
win.title ('My program') #program name on the left top corner
win.minsize(1000,500)
app = App(win)
win.mainloop()


I tried changing height and width, but in the end i got my widget to disappear

What have you tried on changing the width and height of textbox?

I tried changing size with grid, options as height width when i was creating actual widget, tried changing <grid_rowconfigure> and for now nothing helped. My widget keep on being huge

width and height cannot be configured using .grid().  It is better to post a [mre].

It's not entirely clear how you want the text widgets to resize, but if you want them to change dynamically (which I assume based on the sticky='NSWE' portion) when using grid, you'll need to use grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure. These methods are called on the container widget and take the number of the row/column in question, along with a relative weight.
In your case you could add this after the self.master = master line and before self.open_chat() in the __init__:
self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


Btw you can do .grid_rowconfigure((0, 1), weight=1). Not really that useful in this example but great if you have to grid_*configure a lot of rows/columns

Well. I tried the way u told me and go a new mistake:)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'grid_rowconfig'
